# assembly get input and use it as a value

Tags: assembly

I am fairly new to assembly. I am trying to figure out how to read input in assembly, using Emu8086, and have it still be useable as a value.

I have this code:

```
       org  100h

    jmp calc


    message1 db 0dh, 0ah, "input height. $"
    message2 db 0dh, 0ah, "input width. $"                     
    width dw ' ', 20 dup('?')
    height dw ' ', 20 dup('?')
    w dw 0
    h dw 0

    calc: 
    mov dx, offset message1
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h  

    lea dx, width
    mov ah, 0ah 
    int 21h 
    mov bx, dx
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ds:[bx+1]
    add bx, ax
    mov w, ax


    mov dx, offset message2
    mov ah, 9
    int 21h 

    lea dx, height
    mov ah, 0ah 
    int 21h 
    mov bx, dx
    mov ah, 0
    mov al, ds:[bx+1]
    add bx, ax
    mov h, ax



; set video mode 13h - 320x200

code:   mov ah, 0
        mov al, 13h 
        int 10h


    mov cx, w  ; column
    add cx, 100
    mov dx, 20     ; row
    mov al, 15     ; white
u1: mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
    int 10h

    dec cx
    cmp cx, 100
    jae u1

; draw bottom line:

    mov cx, w  ; column
    add cx, 100
    mov dx, h   ; row
    add dx, 20
    mov al, 15     ; white
u2: mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
    int 10h

    dec cx
    cmp cx, 100
    ja u2

; draw left line:

    mov cx, 100    ; column
    mov dx, h   ; row
    add dx, 20
    mov al, 15     ; white
u3: mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
    int 10h

    dec dx
    cmp dx, 20
    ja u3 


; draw right line:

    mov cx, w  ; column
    add cx, 100
    mov dx, h   ; row
    add dx, 20
    mov al, 15     ; white
u4: mov ah, 0ch    ; put pixel
    int 10h

    dec dx
    cmp dx, 20
    ja u4      


; pause the screen for dos compatibility:

;wait for keypress
  mov ah,00
  int 16h           

; return to text mode:
  mov ah,00
  mov al,03 ;text mode 3
  int 10h



ret
```

However, w and h seem to keep the values set at the start of the program, and not take the values from width and height.

**What do I need to do so that `w` and `h` would equal the integer values a user inputs using the program, so I can add them to the numbers near the end?**

Answer (score 0):

`w equ 0` does not declare a variable. What it does is *equate* the symbol `w` with 0, so that all occurrences of `w` in the code will be replaced with a 0. In other words, they are assembly-time constants that you can't change during runtime. I'm surprised that this even assembles (if it does), since `mov 0, ax` doesn't make any sense.

What you should do is declare them as a couple of variables with the initial value that you want. For example:

```
; Declare h and w as words with an initial value of 0
h dw 0   
w dw 0
```

Note that these lines:

```
mov cx, 100+w
mov dx, 20+h
```

also will have to be changed to something like:

```
mov cx,w
add cx,100
mov dx,h
add dx,20
```

Comment: I did that, but the end result is that the values w and h get when I input width and height are not what I typed in, for example, if I input 10 and 5, cx and dx do not end up being 110 and 25, but some other value.

Comment: What you're reading are _strings_. If you want numbers you'll have to convert the strings to their numerical representation (i.e. `"123"` -> `123`).

Comment: for some reason, adding the values like that breaks the rest of the program, even though only the values get changed. I'm updating the post with the full code, even though I'm just using an example program to figure this out.

Comment: In this program, if i set w and h to equ, the program works, but if i change it to dw, it breaks and just draws a line.

Comment: As I wrote before, what you read with `int 21h / ah=0ah` is a string, not an integer. You'll have to take care of converting the strings to numbers yourself. Also, I don't quite get why you're using `[bx+1]`..? Isn't that the number of characters read? The actual string data [should start at `[bx+2]`](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-2563.htm).